# Open and closed set example:

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm exploring different ways of showing a subset $A$ is closed and open.

$X = (1, 5]$ and $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ hence we have metric space $(X,d)$

Take set $A = (1,5] \subseteq X$

**Open:**

$A$ is open because at the point that looks problematic 5, our epsilon ball $B_ε(5)$ essentially has a hard stop on 5, i.e. if $B_ε(5) = \{y \in X | 5 - y| < ε\}$ $B_ε(5)$ doesn't have elements $y\ge 5$

**Closed:**

$A^c = X \setminus A = \emptyset$ as $A = X$

$\therefore A^c$  is vacuously open and closed, hence $A$ is open and closed.

**Boundary:**

The 'possible' boundary points are 1 and 5, but:

$B_ε(5) \cap A^c = \emptyset \land B_ε(1) \cap A^c = \emptyset$

$\therefore \partial A = \emptyset$ (Or should I just say ) $\therefore \require{cancel} \cancel{\exists} \partial A$

Hence $A$ is open and closed!

Are my various approaches correct? Thanks!

Comment: Every topological space is clopen in itself so you don't have to do all that work to show that $(1,5]$ is clopen in $(1,5]$.

Comment: Okay great, I appreciate it, I haven't studied topology specifically (I'm assuming my question would come under topology), but what you're saying makes intuitive sense. That being said, is my reasoning  above still correct?

Comment: Your proof of openness is not very rigorous because you state that $5$ is the problematic point without justification. It is easier than that. You can easily prove that the empty set is both open and closed in any metric space so you can use the same argument as in the second part of your proof to establish that $A$ is both open and closed.

Comment: Okay thanks I appreciate it!